# How can I print the description of an unknown type in Swift?

Tags: swift

How can I create a `dump()` Array extension for printing out all elements in an array?

It's a build error when trying to cast to `Printable` protocol:

```
extension Array {
    func dump() -> String {
        var s = ""
        for x in self {
            if let p = x as? Printable {
                if s != "" { s += ", " }
                s += p.description
            }
        }
        return s
    }
}
```

> 28:26: error: cannot downcast from 'T' to non-@objc protocol type 'Printable'

How can I get a string representation of every element in an Array?

Or is there a way where I can find the `Printable` elements in an Array?

Comment: `Printable` is a protocol that requires you to create a `description : String` getter property. I believe `Array` already supports it, but if not you could create an `extension Array : Printable` with the description read-only property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String interpolation?

```
extension Array {
    func dump() -> String {
        var s = ""
        for x in self {
            let x_str = "\(x)"
            s += x_str
            if !x_str.isEmpty {
                s += ","
            }
        }
        return s
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of `"\(x)"` you can also use `toString(x)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce`, as well:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
arr.reduce("") { $0 == "" ? "\($1)" : "\($0), \($1)" }
// "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9"
```